# Clang plugin issue

Tags: vim, clang, clang-complete

I have installed the plugin [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete). I put these settings in my .vimrc:

```
   let g:clang_use_library      = 1
   let g:clang_auto_select      = 0
   let g:clang_complete_auto    = 1
   let g:clang_complete_copen   = 1
   let g:clang_complete_macros  = 1
   let g:clang_complete_patters = 1
   set completeopt=menu,longest

   let g:clang_library_path = '/usr/lib/clang'
   "let g:clang_library_path = '/usr/lib/llvm-2.9'

   let g:clang_auto_user_options = "-I/usr/include/c++/4.6, .clang_complete"
   let g:clang_snippets = 1
   let g:clang_snippets_engine = 'clang_complete'
```

Every time when I open the .cpp file I have got the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>15_ClangCompleteInit..LoadUserOptions:
line   20:
E121: Undefined variable: getopts#
Loading libclang failed, falling back to clang executable.  Are you sure '/usr/bin/clang' contains libclang?
```

vim is compiled with the python feature. So vim --version is gets:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 28 2012 13:50:08)
Included patches: 1-154

 ... +python -python3 ...  

Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_ATHENA     -Wall -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/usr/include/tcl8.5  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1  
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -Wl,-E  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lXaw -lXmu -lXext -lXt -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -ldl -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.1  -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.12/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions  -L/usr/lib -ltcl8.5 -ldl -lpthread -lieee -lm -lruby1.8 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Can anybody help to resolve the problem?

Comment: Vim version and installation method? Something like this could also easily be because you [didn't install all the files properly](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/issues/171). Also, you might have better luck by [adding an issue over at Github](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/issues). If you do, please post the answer here aswell, if it gets solved on Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here.

1. The value you give for `g:clang_auto_user_options` is invalid. The "path" that the clang_complete documentation mentions doesn't mean that a path should be written in the option string; it refers to using Vim's built-in `'path'` option to provide the list of `-I` flags.

   Use `set g:clang_user_options = "-I/usr/include/c++/4.6"` instead, which just gets passed straight through to clang.

   *Aside:* The `getopts#` in the error occurs because clang_complete tries to interpret your `-I...` string as a part of the name of an options-source function. (The `{anything}` clause in the docs.) The `-` in `getopts#-I/usr/include/c++/4.6#getops()` isn't a valid Vimscript function character so it gets truncated there.
2. clang_complete expects the `g:clang_library_path` directory you specify to contain the `libclang.dylib` or `libclang.so` directly inside of it (e.g. `/usr/lib/clang/libclang.so` in your case).

   Not all distributions of clang provide the libclang shared library, so you might need to compile it yourself.